# How to print console log in reactnative Android?

Tags: react-native

I am using below code to print console log in react native, but i am getting error cannot find variable v:

```
import React, 
{
AppRegistry,
Component,
StyleSheet,
Text,
View,

} from 'react-native';
var ConsolePanel = require('react-native-console-panel').displayWhenDev();


class RanD extends Component {
render() {
return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

          <Text>
          Hit me!
          </Text>

          <View>
          {ConsolePanel}
          </View>
    </View>
  );
  }
 }
```

how to resolve this error??

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Remove this line:

```
var ConsolePanel = require('react-native-console-panel').displayWhenDev();
```

And also remove:

```
{ConsolePanel}
```

To log something to the console in React Native, simply do this:

```
console.log('Hi from React Native');
```

To see the console output, if you're on Mac OS or Linux, run this in a terminal window:

```
$ adb logcat | grep ReactNativeJS
```

If you're on Windows, see this StackOverflow question:
[How to easily view and filter Android's logcat in Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19168643/how-to-easily-view-and-filter-androids-logcat-in-windows)

Reading the logs is also documented in the [Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) guide.

**UPDATE**: You can now run `react-native log-ios` or `react-native log-android` to see the logs in the console.

Comment: hi Martin Konicek .I just place console.log('Hi from React Native'); like this <View> console.log('Hi from React Native'); </View>. I am getting error console.log('Hi from React Native') must be wrapped in explicit <Text> component.

Comment: I placed console.log after import statement .It'sWork.thanks @Martin Konicek

Comment: adb invocation failed. Do you have adb in your PATH? i am getting this error please help me @Martin Konicek